# Wget write log to file and verbose

Tags: logging, wget

I am writing a script that will download Wikipedia dumps. I want wget to write all message to a log file but I also want it to write all message to the screen. Any answer? I use this script and it only write infomation to the log file.

```
wget -r -np -nH -R index.html -a ./$logn-viwikibooks.txt http://dumps.wikimedia.org/viwikibooks/latest/
```

Which

```
logn=`date +%d-%m-%Y'
```

Even if I add '-v' option, there is nothing on the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `tee`:

```
wget -o /dev/stdout -r -np -nH -R index.html http://dumps.wikimedia.org/viwikibooks/latest/ | tee -a ./$logn-viwikibooks.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tail` with `-F` to display "live" the log file as it is appended to.

Run

```
 wget -r -np -nH -R index.html -a ./$logn-viwikibooks.txt http://dumps.wikimedia.org/viwikibooks/latest/
```

and then in another terminal run

```
tail -F ./$logn-viwikibooks.txt
```